# matlab array into "stacked" matrix

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to do the following?

I would like to turn a MATLAB array:

```
>> (1:10)'

ans =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
```

Into the following sequential matrix (I am not sure what is the name for this):

```
ans =

   NaN   NaN   NaN     1
   NaN   NaN   NaN     2
   NaN   NaN   NaN     3
     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6
     4     5     6     7
     5     6     7     8
     6     7     8     9
     7     8     9    10
```

I am able to do this,  with the following function, but it iterates over each row and it is slow:

```
function V = vec2stack(X, num_sequences)
    
n = numel(X);

len_out = n - num_sequences + 1;

V = zeros(len_out,num_sequences);

for kk = 1:len_out
    V(kk,:) = X(kk:kk +num_sequences - 1)';
end
V = [nan(num_sequences,num_sequences); V(1:end-1,:)];
end

X = 1:10;
AA = vec2stack(X,3)
```

Running the above function for a vector of length 1,000,000 takes about 1 second, which is not fast enough for my purposes,

```
tic;
Lag = vec2stack(1:1000000,5);
toc;

Elapsed time is 1.217854 seconds.
```

Comment: I clearly stated the required output. Iterations in MATLAB are suboptimal. I will amend my question to ask if there is a vectorized way to do it.

Comment: Your code doesn't output the column of 1:10 after the three columns. Do you want it to?

Comment: I can easily add that as another column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`repmat()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat the X vector horizontally. Then, notice that each column is one more than the previous. You can add a row-vector that has the same number of columns as the matrix, and Matlab will broadcast the vector onto the entire matrix and do the addition for you.

In older versions of Matlab, you might need to explicitly `repmat()` the row vector to get the shapes to match.

```
function V = vec2stack(X, num_sequences)

    % Repeat X, 1 time vertically, num_seq times horizontally
    % X(:) ensures it's a column vector so we have the correct shape
    mat = repmat(X(:), 1, num_sequences);
    
    % make a row vector from 0:num_sequences-1
    vec = 0:(num_sequences-1);
    
    % or explicitly repmat on vec if you need to:
    % vec = repmat(0:(num_sequences-1), numel(X), 1);
    
    % Add the two. Matlab broadcasts the row vector onto the matrix
    % Because they have the same number of columns
    mat = mat + vec;
    
    % Build the return matrix
    V = [nan(num_sequences, num_sequences); mat];

end

X = (1:10)';
AA = vec2stack(X,3)

% You can easily add the last column as another column
```

Testing speed<sup>on [Octave Online](https://octave-online.net/)</sup>:

```
%% Loopy version
tic;
Lag = vec2stack(1:1000000,5);
toc;

Elapsed time is 17.4092 seconds
```

```
%% Vectorized version
tic;
Lag = vec2stack((1:1000000)',5);
toc;

Elapsed time is 0.110762 seconds.
```

~150x speedup. Pretty cool!

Comment: Pranav, thanks so much, exactly what I needed, and great explanation!

Comment: No worries! Glad to help

Comment: hmm i'm using R2021a but getting "Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation" for `mat = mat + vec`

Comment: `repmat()` the `vec` `numel(X)` times vertically before adding it. Weird because Octave supports it. I thought Matlab started supporting it too a couple versions ago. @tdy

Comment: odd, still getting incompatible sizes with the alternative `vec = repmat(0:(num_sequences-1), numel(X), 1)`, but anyway it seems to work for OP

Comment: @tdy I'm intrigued! Try printing the sizes of the two and see what they say?

Comment: The issue seems to be with `mat = repmat(X, 1, num_sequences)` which currently creates 1x30. i needed to use `mat = repmat(X, num_sequences, 1)'` to make it 10x3. Then it works with either `vec`.

Comment: Ah! Are you calling it with a row-vector? It needs a column-vector. `vec2stack((1:1000000)',5);`

Comment: ah that's it! i used `X=1:10` like OP's post but I see now that yours is `X=(1:10)'`

Comment: Yeah. I was a little sneaky there because OP wanted to turn this array: `(1:10)'` into that matrix. Maybe I should mention that in the answer, though they don't seem to have noticed yet. Or cover that possibility in the function